# `require(variable)` does not not work in next-js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js

I am trying to render image using `next-optimised-images` module. When I try to add images as follows

```
<img src={require(c.logo)} alt={c.title} />
```

I get following error

[image]

But when I hard-code the `src` attribute like

```
<img src={'courses' + require('../../../../mnt/nfs/a@a.com/export/dasdas22dsdd3322a/logo.png')} alt={c.title} />
```

It works fine.

Same error does not occur when I use variable with relative path to image within the project directory such as `require('../' + folder + '/img.png')`.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there any reason why the path in the runtime error is different than the path in your hard-coded src attribute?  What is printed to the console with `console.dir(c.logo)`?

Comment: I just copied and pasted the path from the error into my editor. So there are 3 folders and code breaks randomly on any folder, but when I copy-paste that path, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, but the solution is quite strange. I tried many different ways
such as

```
<img src={require(`${c.logo}`)} alt={c.title} />
```

-- but they did not work.

Then I tried to test by adding local variable `logo = '../folder/logo.png'` and using `<img src={require(logo)} alt={c.title} />` -- it shocked me when this also failed. Then I crazily presses `ctrl` + `z` and saved -- it was working. I noticed that `img` was written as follows

```
<img src={require(\`../folder/${c.logo}\`)} alt={c.title} /> 
// c.logo was computed accordingly after copying the file to the relative path
```

Then I tested for the absolute path `/mnt/nfs/...` by hard-coding the path -- surprising... It was working.

## The crazy solution

All I did is `c.logo = c.logo.replace('/mnt/', '');` and while rendering img

```
<img src={require(`/mnt/${c.logo}`)} alt={c.title} />
```

To my great surprise and relief, this worked perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic or craziness behind this. Webpack just recognizes that you are using a variable path (`/mnt/`) and bundles ALL files inside that path so that's why your variable path works at runtime.
There are two circumstances to take care of:

1. it pre-loads ALL files so all files inside the folder should be importable. For example, if your folder will contain also this `/mnt/fonts/some.ttf` it will break. You should isolate your images to `/mnt/images/` and use this instead of "global" `/mnt/`
2. when changing the content of these dynamic folders (eg adding new logos) it's always good practice to delete the "dist" folder (`.next`) and run the build once more (otherwise hot reload will still load the old files).